# multiple select dropdown in php, and how to check multiple select dropdown values in if condition?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

```
if(isset($_POST['corse_nm'])){
    // $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis WHERE course ='$key' ");    
    
    if($_POST['corse_nm'] == 'all'){
        $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis");
    }
    
    elseif($_POST['corse_nm'] != ''){ 

        // if($_POST['corse_nm'] != ''){
        //     echo "1";
            $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis WHERE course ='".$_POST['corse_nm']."'");
        // }
    }
        elseif(!empty($_POST['corse_nm']) and $_POST['mrks_nm'] > 50 ){
            echo "2";
            $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis WHERE course ='".$_POST['corse_nm']."' and marks > 50 ");
        }
        elseif($_POST['corse_nm'] = 'isselected' || $_POST['mrks_nm'] < 50 ){
            echo "3";
            $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis WHERE course ='".$_POST['corse_nm']."' and marks < 50 ");
        }
        else{
            $sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM regis WHERE course ='".$_POST['corse_nm']."'");
        }
```

in above code `corse_nm` is use for course dropdown and `mrks_nm` is use for marks dropdown, how to check in if condition ?

Comment: Keep in mind you are wide open for sql injections, use parametized queries to safely pass values to your queries.

Comment: show the related HTML as well please.